# can't send/request base64 to azure face api with python

Tags: python, python-requests, face-recognition, azure-api-apps

I want to send the image up on azure face api but it is straightforward to convert the image file to base64 and cannot send requests.

this is code request azure face api,running python but code show error

```py
import requests
import json
import base64

subscription_key = 'my_key'
assert subscription_key

face_api_url = 'https://southeastasia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect'


headers = { 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key }

#data = 'test.jpg'

with open("test.jpg", "rb") as image_file:
    encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
    print(encoded_string)

params = {
    'returnFaceId': 'true',
    'returnFaceLandmarks': 'false',
    'returnFaceAttributes': 'age,gender,headPose,smile,facialHair,glasses,emotion,hair,makeup,occlusion,accessories,blur,exposure,noise',
}

#body={
#    "url": 'data:image/jpeg;base64' + str(encoded_string)
#}
#data={
#    "data": encoded_string,
#    "contentType": "application/octet-stream",
#}

response = requests.post(face_api_url, params=params, headers=headers, json={"data": "image/JPEG;base64,/"+str(encoded_string)})
print(json.dumps(response.json()))
```

this is error:

```
{"error": {"code": "InvalidURL", "message": "Invalid image URL."}}
```

this is correct:

```
[{"faceId": "f9fd11a4-8855-4304-af98-f200afcae843", "faceRectangle": {"top": 621, "left": 616, "width": 195, "height": 195}, "faceAttributes": {"smile": 0.0, "headPose": {"pitch": -11.4, "roll": 7.7, "yaw": 5.3}, "gender": "male", "age": 29.0, "facialHair": {"moustache": 0.4, "beard": 0.4, "sideburns": 0.1}, "glasses": "NoGlasses", "emotion": {"anger": 0.0, "contempt": 0.0, "disgust": 0.0, "fear": 0.0, "happiness": 0.0, "neutral": 0.999, "sadness": 0.001, "surprise": 0.0}, "blur": {"blurLevel": "high", "value": 0.89}, "exposure": {"exposureLevel": "goodExposure", "value": 0.51}, "noise": {"noiseLevel": "medium", "value": 0.59}, "makeup": {"eyeMakeup": true, "lipMakeup": false}, "accessories": [], "occlusion": {"foreheadOccluded": false, "eyeOccluded": false, "mouthOccluded": false}, "hair": {"bald": 0.04, "invisible": false, "hairColor": [{"color": "black", "confidence": 0.98}, {"color": "brown", "confidence": 0.87}, {"color": "gray", "confidence": 0.85}, {"color": "other", "confidence": 0.25}, {"color": "blond", "confidence": 0.07}, {"color": "red", "confidence": 0.02}]}}}, {"faceId": "6c83b2c8-2cdc-43ea-994c-840932601b1d", "faceRectangle": {"top": 693, "left": 1503, "width": 180, "height": 180}, "faceAttributes": {"smile": 0.003, "headPose": {"pitch": -9.0, "roll": -0.5, "yaw": -1.5}, "gender": "female", "age": 58.0, "facialHair": {"moustache": 0.0, "beard": 0.0, "sideburns": 0.0}, "glasses": "NoGlasses", "emotion": {"anger": 0.0, "contempt": 0.001, "disgust": 0.0, "fear": 0.0, "happiness": 0.003, "neutral": 0.984, "sadness": 0.011, "surprise": 0.0}, "blur": {"blurLevel": "high", "value": 0.83}, "exposure": {"exposureLevel": "goodExposure", "value": 0.41}, "noise": {"noiseLevel": "high", "value": 0.76}, "makeup": {"eyeMakeup": false, "lipMakeup": false}, "accessories": [], "occlusion": {"foreheadOccluded": false, "eyeOccluded": false, "mouthOccluded": false}, "hair": {"bald": 0.06, "invisible": false, "hairColor": [{"color": "black", "confidence": 0.99}, {"color": "gray", "confidence": 0.89}, {"color": "other", "confidence": 0.64}, {"color": "brown", "confidence": 0.34}, {"color": "blond", "confidence": 0.07}, {"color": "red", "confidence": 0.03}]}}}]
```

Answer (score 2):

I see you want to send a local image to do the face detection via REST API.

Actually, you just need to change the code of three place to make it works, as below.

1. Add a header `{"Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"}`
2. Read bytes from a file, like `data = open('<your filename>', 'rb').read()`
3. Use `data=data` for binary data instead of `json={...}` for an image url in the `requests.post` method

Here is my sample image `person_of_interest-5.jpg` downloaded from Bing Image.

[image]

And my code is as below.

```
import requests

subscription_key = '<your key>'

face_api_url = 'https://southeastasia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect'

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key,
}

data = open('person_of_interest-5.jpg', "rb").read()

params = {
    'returnFaceId': 'true',
    'returnFaceLandmarks': 'false',
    'returnFaceAttributes': 'age,gender,headPose,smile,facialHair,glasses,emotion,hair,makeup,occlusion,accessories,blur,exposure,noise',
}

response = requests.post(face_api_url, params=params, headers=headers, data=data)
print(response.text)
```

Then, it works and its result be below.

```
[{"faceId":"e07cc105-143e-4ee3-9d84-a2830c8ddd07","faceRectangle":{"top":1501,"left":2582,"width":471,"height":471},"faceAttributes":{"smile":0.391,"headPose":{"pitch":-4.3,"roll":41.8,"yaw":20.8},"gender":"male","age":40.0,"facialHair":{"moustache":0.1,"beard":0.1,"sideburns":0.1},"glasses":"NoGlasses","emotion":{"anger":0.016,"contempt":0.008,"disgust":0.01,"fear":0.0,"happiness":0.391,"neutral":0.569,"sadness":0.003,"surprise":0.003},"blur":{"blurLevel":"medium","value":0.36},"exposure":{"exposureLevel":"goodExposure","value":0.53},"noise":{"noiseLevel":"medium","value":0.52},"makeup":{"eyeMakeup":false,"lipMakeup":false},"accessories":[],"occlusion":{"foreheadOccluded":false,"eyeOccluded":false,"mouthOccluded":false},"hair":{"bald":0.18,"invisible":false,"hairColor":[{"color":"gray","confidence":0.96},{"color":"black","confidence":0.95},{"color":"other","confidence":0.6},{"color":"brown","confidence":0.34},{"color":"blond","confidence":0.12},{"color":"red","confidence":0.02}]}}},{"faceId":"a54d8823-0518-4cb6-942c-4d5357316e69","faceRectangle":{"top":451,"left":1168,"width":427,"height":427},"faceAttributes":{"smile":0.0,"headPose":{"pitch":0.9,"roll":0.0,"yaw":1.0},"gender":"male","age":43.0,"facialHair":{"moustache":0.1,"beard":0.1,"sideburns":0.1},"glasses":"ReadingGlasses","emotion":{"anger":0.0,"contempt":0.0,"disgust":0.0,"fear":0.0,"happiness":0.0,"neutral":0.959,"sadness":0.0,"surprise":0.04},"blur":{"blurLevel":"medium","value":0.66},"exposure":{"exposureLevel":"goodExposure","value":0.66},"noise":{"noiseLevel":"high","value":1.0},"makeup":{"eyeMakeup":false,"lipMakeup":false},"accessories":[{"type":"glasses","confidence":1.0}],"occlusion":{"foreheadOccluded":false,"eyeOccluded":false,"mouthOccluded":false},"hair":{"bald":0.02,"invisible":false,"hairColor":[{"color":"brown","confidence":0.99},{"color":"black","confidence":0.94},{"color":"gray","confidence":0.52},{"color":"other","confidence":0.1},{"color":"red","confidence":0.09},{"color":"blond","confidence":0.03}]}}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Image url is incorrect. As i have used below code  it worked for me.

```
import requests
import json

subscription_key = None
assert subscription_key

face_api_url = 'https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect'

image_url = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/37/Dagestani_man_and_woman.jpg'

headers = { 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key }

params = {
    'returnFaceId': 'true',
    'returnFaceLandmarks': 'false',
    'returnFaceAttributes': 'age,gender,headPose,smile,facialHair,glasses,emotion,hair,makeup,occlusion,accessories,blur,exposure,noise',
}

response = requests.post(face_api_url, params=params, headers=headers, json={"url": image_url})
print(json.dumps(response.json()))
```

Although I would suggest you to use python SDK fro Face which you can install it from here.

```
pip install cognitive_face
```

Face detection is quite easy by doing below

```
import cognitive_face as CF

KEY = '<Subscription Key>'  # Replace with a valid subscription key (keeping the quotes in place).
CF.Key.set(KEY)

BASE_URL = 'https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/'  # Replace with your regional Base URL
CF.BaseUrl.set(BASE_URL)

# You can use this example JPG or replace the URL below with your own URL to a JPEG image.
img_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Face-Windows/master/Data/detection1.jpg'
faces = CF.face.detect(img_url)
print(faces)
```

Here is the sample response

```
[{'faceId': '26d8face-9714-4f3e-bfa1-f19a7a7aa240', 'faceRectangle': {'top': 124, 'left': 459, 'width': 227, 'height': 227}}]
```

Hope it helps.