# How can i send a base64 image to Azure Face-API with curl?

Tags: azure, curl, base64, azure-cognitive-services

as my question mention it, how do i need to change this statement to send an image in base64 to Azure?

```
curl -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: ***hidden***" "https://***hidden***.cognitiveservices.azure.com/face/v1.0/detect?detectionModel=detection_03&returnFaceId=true&returnFaceLandmarks=false" 
-H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-ascii "{\"url\":\"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c3/RH_Louise_Lillian_Gish.jpg\"}"
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> how do i need to change this statement to send an image in base64 to Azure?

As per this [documentation](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236), your curl command seems fine.

Alternatively, you can try as suggested by [muru](https://askubuntu.com/questions/650391/send-base64-encoded-image-using-curl):

```
'{"image" : "'"$( base64 ~/Pictures/1.jpg)"'"}
```

**Updated answer:**

As per [Use the Face client library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/quickstarts/client-libraries?tabs=visual-studio&pivots=programming-language-rest-api#identify-faces):

```
curl -v -X POST "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect?returnFaceId=true&returnFaceLandmarks=false&returnFaceAttributes={string}&recognitionModel=recognition_04&returnRecognitionModel=false&detectionModel=detection_03&faceIdTimeToLive=86400" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: {subscription key}" --data-ascii "{\"url\":\"https://csdx.blob.core.windows.net/resources/Face/Images/identification1.jpg\"}"
```

You can refer to similar issues: [can't send/request base64 to azure face api with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56405595/cant-send-request-base64-to-azure-face-api-with-python) and [Face API need support for base64 string or Local File URL or Native File URL instead of Image URL](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/50029)

Comment: `curl --location --request POST 'https://ge***nd.cognitiveservices.azure.com/face/v1.0/detect?returnFaceId=true&returnFaceLandmarks=false&recognitionModel=recognition_04&returnRecognitionModel=false&detectionModel=detection_03&faceIdTimeToLive=86400' --header 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: 562*******ff' --header 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' --data-binary '{"image" : "'"$( base64 /Users/rafael/Downloads/myimage.jpg)"'"}`

It doesn't work. My terminal is doing nothing not, no response, no path is shown anymore. Can you write down the full statement please?

Thank you very much!

Comment: The ' at the end was missing. Statement is now working but response is {"error":{"code":"InvalidImage","message":"Decoding error, image format unsupported."}} not matter which picture, format file, encoding tools I am using..

Comment: [How to send application/octet-stream image to Face API](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/dcca3366-8ff8-4a1b-94f0-33ecdd369004/how-to-send-applicationoctetstream-image-to-face-api?forum=mlapi) and ["Decoding error, image format unsupported" in Microsoft Face API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36120746/decoding-error-image-format-unsupported-in-microsoft-face-api)

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I have already seen the contributions, but could not transfer it to my question. I have now got the working curl statement from someone else.

Answer (score 0):

curl -X POST "https://******.cognitiveservices.azure.com/face/v1.0/detect" -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: 27e993***************6aaa2464" --data-binary @'/home/rafael/Downloads/person.jpg'

is the solution that works. As far as I can tell, the documentation seems outdated.